# plot netcdf data

Tags: r, ggplot2, netcdf

I want to plot this kind of netcdf file:

```
    3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    float SOMO35[ncl1,ncl0]   
    float xlon[ncl3,ncl2]   
    float xlat[ncl5,ncl4]
```

Just some simple, files with SOMO35 variable, latitudes, and longitudes.

This is the code I wrote, but I have no output, Where am I doing wrong?

```
library(chron)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(sf)
memory.limit(size=56000)

file <- "SOMO35_D04_AIX_Control.nc"
ncin <- nc_open(file)
print(ncin) # Displays plenty of information about netCDF
lat <-ncvar_get(ncin,"xlat")
lon <-ncvar_get(ncin,"xlon")
somo <- ncvar_get(ncin,"SOMO35")

image(somo)
somo.df = data.frame(lat, lon, somo)

graph <-ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=somo.df, aes(lon, lat))+
 ggtitle("")+
 xlab('Longitude')+
 ylab('Latitude')+
 coord_fixed()
```